# Concatenate values of a string column in pandas dataframe and add slash notation

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, concatenation

I want to concatenate all values of a string column in pandas dataframe and add "\cite{" and "}" at the beginning and end of the obtained string, respectively. The below code works but generate double slash. df is the dataframe and "ref" is a string column with values such as Den2013, Tur2017, Gil2010, ... .

```
 '\cite{' + ', '.join(df['ref']) + '}'
```

The output of the above code considering only three observations of Den2013, Tur2017, Gil2010 is:

```
'\\cite{Den2013, Tur2017, Gil2010}'
```

I need only one slash "\" but it generates "\\". I tried searching internet, but could not find anything. Any thoughts what is happening here? Appreciate your response.

Comment: your code works fine. \\ is just how python represents the backslash, which is the escape character. Print that string and you would see the single backslash.

Comment: Thanks Quang, yes you are right. I am wondering if I need to remove my question or leave it as a  reference for this type of discussions.